# PHP SimpleXMLElement validation with XSD

Tags: php, xml, validation, xsd

is it possible to validate a SimpleXMLElement with an XSD shema stored in a string?

I get this xml trough CURL:

```
<production_feedback>
        <production_number>DA1100208</production_number>
    <production_status>DONE</production_status>
</production_feedback>
```

On my side i get it like this:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ){

    $post_text = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($post_text);

    error_log(print_r($xml , true));
    }
```

This is in my `error_log()` :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object\n(\n    [production_number] => DA1100208\n    [production_status] => PRODUCTION_IN_PROGRESS\n)\n
```

So i can access the data with Xpath. This works well. I would like to validate it with an XSD. Is it possible, or is there any other way 2 validate the XML string with the XSD string?

this is my XSD btw stored in a variable:

```
$production_XSD ='<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="production_feedback">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="production_number"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="production_status"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SimpleXMLElement class doesn't support that (as far as the documentation on php.net is up to date).

The [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) provides the functionality you're looking for using the DOMDocument::schemaValidateSource method.

---- Original

The [XMLReader](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) class however has the setSchema method which can be used for validation against a XSD **file** (It's not exactly what you were looking for, but that's what I found without relying on any external libraries)

Comment: Yeah, I think so. (You could just write the file and delete it afterwards again, but I don't know if you want to do that)

When using a RelaxNG Schema however you could pass the schema string directly to the setRelaxNGSchemaSource method (But I don't know Relax NG, so I can't advise you on whether it is a good way to go or not).

Comment: I just found the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) class which supports validating an XML against a schema string using the DOMDocument::schemaValidateSource method. You might wanna give that a try instead.

Comment: i found this http://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.xml.php  i think i dont have to save it, just set a string. Correct me if im false.

Comment: The XMLReader::xml method parses an XML string, it doesn't validate it against an XSD schema.

Comment: one last comment , it works perfect with DOMDocument class, with loadXML and schemaValidateSource. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to validate a var containing an XML string against an XSD file, so if anyone else is looking for this solution, please see below:

```
// $xml_feed is a string containing your XML content
// validate xml string with xsd file
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml_feed); // load xml
$is_valid_xml = $doc->schemaValidate('XSDs/FeedFile.xsd'); // path to xsd file

if (!$is_valid_xml){
    echo '<b>Invalid XML:</b> validation failed<br>';
}else{
    echo '<b>Valid XML:</b> validation passed<br>';
}
```

If you also have your XSD stored in a string, then replace 'XSDs/FeedFile.xsd' with the var containing your XSD.. hope someone finds this helpful!